# How to get `netstat -tpn`-like output with `ip` utility

Tags: linux, ip, netstat

How (or is it possible) to list all open TCP(/UDP) ports using `ip` utility on Linux (preferably with their owner processes)? I want something like `netstat -tpn`.

Comment: The `ip` utility doesn't do that.

Comment: ip netns pids NAME